# Laravel редирект с http на https - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel

Apache настроен на папку `publiс` внутри проекта laravel 6.0. Внутри `publiс` присутствует файл `.htaccess` следующего содержания (из коробки)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Если добавить в конец файла перенаправление с http на https, то на локальном сервере (laragon) всё работает отлично, а на хостинге вылетает ошибка `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` (Сайт ... выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # HTTP to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Точно такая же ошибка на хостинге, если использовать `middleware` вместо модификации `.htaccess`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure()) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

С чем это может быть связано? Что за ерунда?

Comment: Вероятно с тем, что хостинг не поддерживает `%{HTTPS}`. А что он поддерживает, лучше уточнять у хостинга